# Is is possible for a quadratic equation with only one irrational root to have integral coefficients?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Given a quadratic equation with one and only one root  (for example $6-\sqrt{2}$ ). Does there exist integers $a,b$ and $c$ where $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ for that root?

Comment: I don't think a quadratic equation with rational coefficients can have only one irrational root.

Comment: $x^2 -2=0$ repeated root

Comment: No. that's 2 roots. sqrt(2) and -sqrt(2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not even if the coefficients are rational.
If a quadratic equation
has $r$ and $s$ as roots,
it can be written as
$(x-r)(x-s)
=x^2-(r+s)x + rs
$.

If the coefficients are rational,
then
$r+s$ is rational,
so $r$ and $s$
are both rational
or both irrational.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. given $r_1 = 6-\sqrt{2}$, we know that $r_2 = 6+\sqrt{2}$

so the quadratic equation is given by

$(x-(6-\sqrt{2}))(x-(6+\sqrt{2}))=(x-6)^2-2 = x^2-12x+34$

Comment: What if 6−sqrt(2) is the only root? the parabola max or min intercepts the x axis at the point (x,y)  (0, 6-sqrt(2))?

Comment: @Aheho The question only ask if there exist a quadratic equation with integer coefficient, and the construction gurantee and integer value for a,b and c. Now they is a quadratic equation that correspond to the situation when $6-\sqrt{2}$ is a repeated root, but that polynomial does not have integer coefficient

Comment: I changed the wording to make my intent clearer

Answer (score 0):

When there is only one root, the discriminant is zero and the root is $\frac{-b}{2a}$ because $\frac{-b+0}{2a}$ and $\frac{-b-0}{2a}$ are both equal to $\frac{-b}{2a}$

It is impossible for a quadratic equation with integer coefficients to have only one irrational root because $\frac{-b}{2a}$ will always be rational when the coefficients are integers. That's simply because a rational number is defined as a number that can be expressed as a ratio of two integers.